# Recent Documents" Web Parts on Classic Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-search-web-part, classic-experience, graph-api

I would like users to view the most recent documents. I know this web part is part of the communication site for modern sites.

Can I replicate the same in a classic page?

Looking for some ideas/options ..maybe search api or graph?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Microsoft graph "recent files" endpoint which lists a set of items that have been recently used by the signed in user.

You can find more information in this documentation: [List recent files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. But do you have any examples or steps to connect using a logged in user to graph api. I know i need an access token etc..I tried using response post call in  ajax but i keep getting error 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token/' from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript